# How do I match a path with a regex? (right way to quote?)

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am trying to find the regex to match a path of the format `./foo/baz/bar/filename.c` in a `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` context.

I would expect the `regex=$'(^\./).*$'` to match, but `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` stays empty. I tried to escape the parentheses or to leave away the `.*` with no avail.

I have found out about the nice way how the access to nested capturing-groups works via `BASH_REMATCH` with other `$string` contents (one additional index for nesting-level and capturing-group to the right), but this one I can't get to match.

What is my failure?

Comment: It works for me. `regex=$'(^\./).*$' ; [[ ./foo/baz/bar/filename.c =~ $regex  ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`. Even with plain `regex='(^\./).*$'`.

Comment: Weird. Than the cause must be false quoting of the string. Probable, right?

Comment: Because when I replace `$string` in my example by `./foo/baz/bar/filename.c` directly, then it too matches. How would you quote the string to be matched to save it in a variable?

Comment: Ok, the `$string` must also either be quoted by `$'...'` or by `'...'`, then it works. Btw,: If a dollar sign prepending single quotes makes special characters not lose their meaning, where is the difference to double-quotes?

Comment: What? Do you say `[[ '$string' =~ $regex ]]` works for you?

Comment: `$'...'` enables ANSI C escapes. Unlike `"`, it doesn't do any expansions.

Comment: @choroba No, I say `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` works for me if I put the value of `$string` in either `$'...'` or just `'...'` instead of `"..."`

Comment: That's weird. Does $string contain some special characters?

Comment: Yes, a point. Why is that weird? Can you explain if it is a syntax quirk or something?

Comment: See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653925/how-to-extract-multiple-occurences-of-one-capturing-group-from-a-regex-match `string='./foo/baz/bar/filename.c'`

Comment: For this path, it should work equally without quotes.

Comment: This is just an example. The paths that my script processes may contain whitespaces too. (But no newlines or tabs)

Comment: Yes, spaces must be quoted or escaped. It's not related to regex matching, that's how the shell interprets the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Works with the `$string` variable in `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]` also being quoted either in `$'...'` or in single-quotes `'...'` without prepended dollar-sign.