# How to extract multiple occurences of one capturing-group from a regex-match?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have a string of following format to be matched

```
./foo/baz/bar/filename.c
```

My regex looks like this

```
  regex=$'^(\./)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/)+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+)$'
```

The test looks like this

```
[[ $search =~ $regex ]]
```

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251013/bash-regex-capture-group) thread there is an interesting code [code example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251031/440130) example by user [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) in order to capture repeated occurences of the same capturing-group

```
global_rematch() { 
    local s=$1 regex=$2 
    while [[ $s =~ $regex ]]; do 
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        s=${s#*"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"}
    done
}
global_rematch "$mystring1" "$regex"
```

But in the regex there, there is only **one** capturing group. **My** case here is a little different.

My $regex tries to extract multiple occurences of one capturing-group. But that capturing group is treated lazily (or what is the correct term here? `global matching` ?) and it only outputs its' first occurence. The others are discarded.

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
./foo/baz/bar/filename.c
./
bar/
filename.c
```

All occurences are only put out when I add an additional pair of parentheses, but that's not the result what I want.

```
regex=$'^(\./)?(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/)+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+)$'
```

The result is

```
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
foo/baz/bar/
```

Is there a way to apply the code example above or another solution such that all repeated occurences are stored in `BASH_REMATCH` by an own index instead ?

Such that the indices would be something like this:

```
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
./foo/baz/bar/filename.c
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
./
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
foo/
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
baz/
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
bar/
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
filename.c
```

Maybe I just have to run two pattern matchings, one with only one capturing group. As workaround.

Comment: Glenn's code won't work here since you have the `(\./)?` in your regex because that will be removed by the first run of the `while` in the `global_rematch` function, but because of the `?`, the string will keep on matching for ever. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) though. Can you explain what you will be doing with this array downstream in your program? We may be able to give a different approach. If all you want is to separate the path into each component part, there are better ways than regular expression matching.

Comment: Actually, is this question maybe obsolete now that you have gotten an answer to [your newer one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653959/22222)?

Comment: Is this still an issue? Or should the question be closed/deleted?

Comment: It's still an issue if there is a rather quick solution. Otherwise I'll have to  break the problem of matching the parts I am intersting in in sub-problems by parameter-expansion and pattern-matching to reduce the string step by step by those parts. Would you know a  faster, more convenient way, where `foo/baz/bar` each get an own index, like ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} => `foo/`, ${BASH_REMATCH[4]} => `baz/`, ${BASH_REMATCH[5]} => `bar/`