# How do I split a string by a delimiter resulting in an unknown number of parts and how can I collect the results in an array?

Tags: bash, array, bash-array

I need to process some strings containing paths. How do I split such a string by `/` as delimiter resulting in an unknown number of path-parts and how do I, in the end, extract the resulting path-parts?

`cut` is obviously not the tool of choice as it needs you to know the number of parts beforehand and it also doesn't output each part such that I could use `readarray` or `mapfile` to collect them into an array.

Comment: Note that depending on what you're doing, `dirname` and `basename` might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, you can use `read -a` and a here-string to split the string into an array:

```
path=/foo/bar/doo
IFS=/ read -r -a parts <<< "$path"
```

That would give an array with the four elements (empty), `foo`, `bar`, and `doo`.

That doesn't work with paths containing newlines, since `read` treats the newline as a separator by default. To prevent that, you'd need to add `-d ''`, but then there's the problem that the here-string adds a newline, which then must be removed from the last element:

```
path=$'/path/with/new\nlines'
IFS=/ read -d '' -r -a parts <<< "$path"
parts[-1]=${parts[-1]%$'\n'}
```

(`parts[-1]` refers to the last element of the array, and `${var%text}` expands to the value of `var` with the trailing part matching `text` removed.)

Also note that if the path can contain duplicate slashes, e.g. `foo//bar`, you'll get empty array elements in the middle. Similarly if the path ends with a slash, you'll get an empty element at the end.

You could either ignore them, or preprocess the path to remove them, with something like this, to remove duplicate slashes

```
shopt -s extglob
path="${path//+('/')/'/'}"
```

and to remove trailing slashes:

```
shopt -s extglob
path="${path%+('/')}"
```

But then again, note that at the start of a pathname, a double slash `//foo` is a reserved special notation, different from a single (or triple etc.) slash, but you're not likely to see that in practice, so I'll ignore it.

Comment: Thanks especially for mentioning the caveat with the herestring adding a `\n`ewline :)

Comment: See also [Shell read \*sometimes\* strips trailing delimiter](//stackoverflow.com/q/52762210) on SO about the behaviour when the input ends in the delimiter.

Comment: Ah, right, `IFS=/ read -r -a arr <<< "/foo/bar/"`, doesn't produce the empty tailing field. But `IFS=/ read -d '' -r -a arr <<< "/foo/bar/"` it does produce one with just the newline character

Answer (score 5):

In `bash`, for single character delimiters, you can use the split+glob operator (leaving expansions unquoted in list contexts) after having disabled the glob part:

```
string='foo/bar
baz/asd..'

IFS=/
set -o noglob
array=( $string )
```

Note that it splits `string='/foo/'` into `""` and `"foo"` only (the same as when splitting `string='/foo'`. To split into `""`, `"foo"` and `""`, you can do:

```
IFS=/
set -o noglob
array=( $string'' )
```

Though that then splits `string=''` into one empty element instead of zero element.

In `zsh` (which doesn't do split+glob upon unquoted expansion unless in `sh`/`ksh` emulation), you can use the `s` parameter expansion flag which is not limited to single-character delimiters:

```
array=( ${(s[/])string} )
```

which removes empty elements, or:

```
array=( "${(@s[/])string}" )
```

To preserve empty elements. `/foo/` is then split into `""`, `"foo"` and `""` and the empty string into zero element.

You can split on a delimiter stored in a variable with:

```
array=( "${(@ps[$delimiter])string}" )
```

The `p` flag also lets you enter escape sequences such as `\0`, `\n`, though those two have shortcut flags: `f` to split on linefeed, `0` to split on NUL (useful to split the output of `find -print0`, `grep -lZ`, `sort -z`... such as `files=( ${(0)"$(grep -lZ pattern -- *)"} )`).

In `zsh`, you can also *tie* an array variable to a scalar variable with a given single byte as delimiter. `$path` in `zsh` is actually a special array that is ties to `$PATH` with `:` as delimiter in that fashion (inspired from `csh`). You can do that for any variable like:

```
typeset -T string array /
```

To tie `/`-separated `$string` to the `$array` array.

Answer (score 3):

> ... doesn't output each part such that I could use `readarray` or `mapfile`

With mapfile/readarray, provide the complete string and set a delimiter. For example,

```
str='/f
oo/bar/'

mapfile -d / arr < <(printf '%s' "$str")

declare -p arr
```

outputs:

```
declare -a arr=([0]="/" [1]=$'f\noo/' [2]="bar/")
```

Comment: plus the `-t` flag to have `mapfile` remove the terminators, if you like.